# Get Windows User name in ASP.NET HTML Page

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an asp.net application and in that I have a html page.

I need to get the Windows username in that html page.

I understand its not possible in normal page.

I need to achieve this without using ActiveX objects.

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a place for people to do your work for you.

Comment: You said 'html page' and 'normal page' but you are trying answers which clearly need aspx/runat="server" so it would suggest to me the page isn't necessarily static html. Can you please be clearer on exactly what you are asking and what you have attempted so far? I'm voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create an AJAX call on your page to some WebMethod in your ASP.NET application that call will return you user name.

it basicaly comes down to placeing request to the WebMethod like this

the call below gets data from WebMothod and displays it in the div in the page

```
 $.get('jqueryintro.htm', function (data) {
                $('#maindiv').html(data);
            });
```

If you will need more information you can [use this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/using-jquery-ajax-functions-to-retrieve-data-from-the-server) very easy to follow article.
And don't forget to include jQuery ($) in your page

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Windows authentication enabled on the site and the user is authenticated you can put this in your ASPX:

```
<p><%= User.Identity.Name %></p>
```

The above code embeds the username in the HTML that is sent to the client.

An AJAX request is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
<div runat="server"><%= System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name %></div>
<div runat="server"><%= User.Identity.Name %></div>
<div runat="server"><%= Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].ToString() %></div>
```

As long as you are using Windows Auth it should work, otherwise you would just get the account info for whatever IIS is running under.

Any container with `runat="server"` should work really it doesn't have to be a `div`.

Comment: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name Worked for me when i run directly in Visual studio. But when i host my application is IIS, it returned "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool"

Comment: Your app will need to be using windows based authentication in IIS for any approach to work. Otherwise you will just get the account info for what the IIS process is running under.